# Есть 2 страницы в Wordpress , главная и страница(шаблон)

Tags: wordpress

```
             <?php query_posts('cat=4');
             
                     the_post(); ?>


                    <h3 class="main_news_post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3><br>
                <p class="main_news_post_text"><?php the_content(); ?></p><br>
                <p class="main_news_post_data"><?php the_date('j F Y'); ?>  


        </div>
```

Когда делаю посты они отображаются на главной, но когда хочу открыть выбранный(определенный) пост и отобразить его на странице шаблоне выводится последний пост независимо какой пост будет выбран на главной.

Comment: Это что за кусок кода? Он относится к single записи или к чему-то другому?

Comment: Собственно, к чем здесь `query_posts('cat=4'); the_post();`?

Comment: Этот кусок в шаблоне странице в том месте где мне нужно выводить 1 пост, query_posts('cat=4') это для того что бы на эту страницу приходили посты из рубрики ID-4

Comment: В шаблоне `single.php`, по-умолчанию выводится 1 пост, из той категории, из которой он должен выводиться при переходе по ссылке. В чем смысл при переходе на пост из категории, например 2, выводить туда пост из категории 4? Или в чем смысл данного шаблона? Зачем в шаблон страницы, если это шаблон именно страницы, выводить пост, если у поста есть свой шаблон?

Comment: Для каждой категории есть свой "личный" шаблон страницы с разной побочной инф, и при клике на пост должно переходить на эту "личную" страницу которая сделана для постов из категории 4. При клике на пост например на категорию 2 должно переходить на "личную" страницу  2. Но при переходе выводит только последнюю новость данной категории, не зависимо на какую новость  кликаешь первая, вторая или пятая на страницу выводит только последнюю новость из данной категории. На все страницы посты рубрик приходят правильно, но отображает только последнюю запись

Comment: Это немного свой велосипед, или не немного) Добавьте примеры кода Ваших шаблонов в вопрос и объясните зачем это. Смотря на `query_posts('cat=4'); the_post();` и то что ниже Вы выводите заголовок с контентом, Вам никто не поможет (не достаточно информации), а использование query_posts() -- плохая практика. На всякий случай, для категорий так же можно создать свой шаблон и его можно даже для каждой из категорий сделать свой, [иерархия шаблонов в WordPress](https://wp-kama.ru/id_7654/ierarhiya-fajlov-temy-shablona.html)

Comment: https://wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/

Comment: Нашел решение! на главную странице(где все посты)  the_permalink  принимает get_post() , который рендерится по факту добавления поста  <?php the_permalink(get_post()) ?> и тем самым отсортировав все категории выбираем query_posts('cat=4');  пробегая циклом и выводим наш пост в нужном месте. Теперь буду разбираться с  query_posts, чем он так плох. Спасибо Simon, натолкнул на мысль